# Reference of language aspects of Mathematics.

Tags: reference-request, philosophy

I occasionally wonder about the language aspects of Mathematics. Like when I read Vilém Flusser, Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus by Wittgenstein and Godel's Proof by Ernest Nagel and James Newman.

Some weeks ago I took a mini course about Historiography and Literature. Since then my interest sparked again.

By "language" I don't mean "language of the universe", "universal language" or something alike. But thinking about the symbols, syntax, meaning and "the worlds created by the writter (mathematician)".

I didn't get good results when I tried to look it by myself, so I aske for references here.

Comment: Not very clear... From a more mathematical point of view, maybe useful: Marcel Danesi, Language and Mathematics: An Interdisciplinary Guide (de Gruyter, 2016) and Jacek Woźny, How We Understand Mathematics: Conceptual Integration in the Language of Mathematical Description (2018 Springer)

Comment: For more specifically mathematical logic topics, see Yu. Manin, [A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians (2010)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Course_in_Mathematical_Logic_for_Mathe/TATTwAEACAAJ)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, it's not very clear. I have this hazy idea of what I want to study but I didn't read enough to even be clear. I'll start with Jacek Woźny. Many thanks.